# create column names algorithmically for for large datasets in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

I'm looking to import a massive dataset into a mysql server. The issue is that the first 6 columns are fine to name, after that I have over 1000 columns of absorption values and I'd rather not sit there typing 'absorp-x' for hours. Is there a way to specify the first few column names when I create a table and then say "use the following format for all columns: absorp-x"?

Comment: Bad idea, MySQL has a hard limit defined (which is around 1024 i believe) for the max amount off columns in a table...

Comment: My research suggests you can have up to 4096 columns per table subject to a few conditions

Comment: *"My research suggests you can have up to 4096 columns per table subject to a few conditions "* ..... *"Maximums and Minimums

    A table can contain a **maximum of 1017 columns**. Virtual generated columns are included in this limit"*.   ->  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html  ... InnoDB  is pretty much the default table engine which you should be using anyway as MyISAM is on it way to deprecation..

Comment: Why do i think or say that MyISAM is on its way to deprecation? The manual suggests/hints to that when i read the manual about the [internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine) setting ... -> *"
Important

In MySQL 8.0.16 and later, on-disk internal temporary tables always use the InnoDB storage engine; as of MySQL 8.0.16, this variable has been removed and is thus no longer supported"*

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you throw the 1000 absorption values into a JSON string and have a single column for that data.  In that situation, you don't need to name the values but simply have a JSON array.  (I assume they are numbered consecutively?)

That would probably fit into a `TEXT CHARACTER SET ascii` column.  Or, if you have a newer version, a `JSON` column.